# Django m2m 'through' with a generic foreignkey

Tags: django-models

I have the follow code example, which is a simplified abstraction of a real world project I'm working on:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class FeatureSet(models.Model):
    """
    Feature Set
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.name

class GenericObjectAlpha(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    feature_sets = models.ManyToManyField(FeatureSet, through='Feature')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.title

class GenericObjectBeta(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    feature_sets = models.ManyToManyField(FeatureSet, through='Feature')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.title         

class Feature(models.Model):
    """
    Feature
    """
    # FK to feature set
    feature_set = models.ForeignKey(FeatureSet)

    # FK to generic object, Generic object alpha or beta... or others
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        default='article',
        limit_choices_to={ 'model__in': ('genericobjectalpha', 'genericobjectbeta') },
        related_name="play__feature_set__feature")
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        "Feature object lookup")
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey(
        'content_type', 
        'object_id')

    # Extra fields on a m2m relationship
    active = models.BooleanField()
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s::%s" % (self.feature_set, self.content_object)
```

This line causes an error:

```
feature_sets = models.ManyToManyField(FeatureSet, through='Feature')
```

Obviously because the 'through' model lacks a corresponding FK to each side of the m2m.  What I'd like to achieve here, is that one side of the m2m relationship is generic, and, that I can specify my own intermediary join table, to do the usual adding of custom fields etc.

What are my options for accomplishing this?

Note, its currently an important requirement to include the `feature_sets = models.ManyToManyField(FeatureSet, through='Feature')` line in the generic model, mostly for admin UI purposes.  The reason why its generic is that its not yet determined how many models this line will be placed upon.